# Modeling length of events

Tags: r, regression

In `N` individuals observed over respective `Tn` times, I have observed Kn events. Multiple events pro individual N can be observed Kni (where i is the index numder for the k event of the n individual).

With a set of `X` predictors (predictors on the individuals `Xn` and of each specific episode `Xkni`).  I would like to model the length of the `K` events (`Lnki`), and try do find which of the `Xn` and `Xkni` influence `L`.

`L` are integers > 0

What would be the appropriate was to run such regression? Poisson? Maybe a mixed model (with N random intercepts?). Any help with links to R resources is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the jargon for what you are interested in "survival analysis", e.g., https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/199744/using-survival-analysis-with-multiple-events

Comment: No, I am not interested in survival analysis.

Comment: Why not? The description of your problem sounds exactly like a survival analysis problem.

Comment: I am not interested to see if the events occur or when the events occur but on the length on the events. I dont undestand how to formulate this as a survival analysis problem.